# How to get list of instances attached to ELB in form of comma separated list

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to get list of all instances attached to an ELB (need to use them in further processing).

Here is what I have done so far :

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name 'my-elb' --output json --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].Instances[*].InstanceId"
```

However, above command gives me the list in JSON format.

```
[
    [
        "i-05676776d8cd4ab5344b0d",
"i-05676776"
    ]
]
```

How can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `--output text` and post the output.

Comment: output text does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer to get comma separated list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--output text` and pipe it to `paste`

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name 'my-elb' --output text --query "LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].Instances[*].InstanceId" | paste -d, -s
```