# aws ec2 text output printing on multiple lines

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, export-to-csv, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to extract some pertinent information about some of my ELB instances using the following query

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name my-elb \
 --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName, DNSName, Scheme ,\
 SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName , SecurityGroups, Instances[*].InstanceId ]
```

The output looks as follows

```yaml
- - - my-elb
    - my-elb-15451562.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
    - internet-facing
    - my-elb-sg
    - - sg-ef113b0d
    - - i-00633c0d3a103b3e9
```

My question is: when I do `--output text` then the last two elements end up on a separate line each. This ruins the TSV format and subsequent input into LibreCalc.

How can I prevent this so the import of the TSV shows up on one line?

Comment: If your open to changing the command output format to JSON it's a lot easier...  You can then pipe the output to something like `jq` to extract the fields you want and reformat them however you like.  That should make parsing/transforming the output easier.  But if there are issues (like the one-to-many nature of the data elements mentioned elsewhere) then the problem is deeper than parsing the output.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there is a **one-to-many relationship** between ELBs and Instances. One ELB can link to multiple instances. This makes it difficult to display as a CSV/TSV because the number of columns is variable.

If you know that there is a **fixed number of instances** always associated with that ELB, then you could change the query to:

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --load-balancer-name my-elb \
 --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[LoadBalancerName, DNSName, Scheme ,\
 SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName , SecurityGroups, Instances[0].InstanceId, Instances[1].InstanceId ]
```

Comment: `SecurityGroups` is an array too, so it should be `SecurityGroups[0]`. But I would say, if we want to go this route, the flatten operator works wonders

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the results I wanted by piping to the paste command `| paste -d"\t" -s`

I wonder of there are SED or AWK solutions when there are unknown new lines ?

Comment: Similar solution can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42706884/how-to-get-list-of-instances-attached-to-elb-in-form-of-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 1):

You can actually go around this issue by creating an artificial array of array, then use the [flatten operator — `[]`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#flatten-operator) —  on this artificial array.

Given the JSON:

```json
{
  "LoadBalancerDescriptions": [
    {
      "Subnets": [
          "subnet-15aaab61"
      ],
      "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID": "Z3DZXE0EXAMPLE",
      "CanonicalHostedZoneName": "my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
      "ListenerDescriptions": [
          {
              "Listener": {
                  "InstancePort": 80,
                  "LoadBalancerPort": 80,
                  "Protocol": "HTTP",
                  "InstanceProtocol": "HTTP"
              },
              "PolicyNames": []
          },
          {
              "Listener": {
                  "InstancePort": 443,
                  "SSLCertificateId": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:server-certificate/my-server-cert",
                  "LoadBalancerPort": 443,
                  "Protocol": "HTTPS",
                  "InstanceProtocol": "HTTPS"
              },
              "PolicyNames": [
                  "ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-03"
              ]
          }
      ],
      "HealthCheck": {
          "HealthyThreshold": 2,
          "Interval": 30,
          "Target": "HTTP:80/png",
          "Timeout": 3,
          "UnhealthyThreshold": 2
      },
      "VPCId": "vpc-a01106c2",
      "BackendServerDescriptions": [
          {
              "InstancePort": 80,
              "PolicyNames": [
                  "my-ProxyProtocol-policy"
              ]
          }
      ],
      "Instances": [
          {
              "InstanceId": "i-207d9717"
          },
          {
              "InstanceId": "i-afefb49b"
          }
      ],
      "DNSName": "my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
      "SecurityGroups": [
          "sg-a61988c3"
      ],
      "Policies": {
          "LBCookieStickinessPolicies": [
              {
                  "PolicyName": "my-duration-cookie-policy",
                  "CookieExpirationPeriod": 60
              }
          ],
          "AppCookieStickinessPolicies": [],
          "OtherPolicies": [
              "my-PublicKey-policy",
              "my-authentication-policy",
              "my-SSLNegotiation-policy",
              "my-ProxyProtocol-policy",
              "ELBSecurityPolicy-2015-03"
          ]
      },
      "LoadBalancerName": "my-load-balancer",
      "CreatedTime": "2015-03-19T03:24:02.650Z",
      "AvailabilityZones": [
          "us-west-2a"
      ],
      "Scheme": "internet-facing",
      "SourceSecurityGroup": {
          "OwnerAlias": "123456789012",
          "GroupName": "my-elb-sg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

<sup>*taken as example from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elb/describe-load-balancers.html#examples*</sup>

The query:

```
LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[ [LoadBalancerName, DNSName, Scheme, SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName, SecurityGroups, Instances[*].InstanceId][] ]
```

Would yield the JSON

```json
[
  [
    [
      "my-load-balancer",
      "my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com",
      "internet-facing",
      "my-elb-sg",
      "sg-a61988c3",
      "i-207d9717",
      "i-afefb49b"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Which is an equivalent of the YAML

```yaml
- - - my-load-balancer
    - my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
    - internet-facing
    - my-elb-sg
    - sg-a61988c3
    - i-207d9717
    - i-afefb49b
```

---

Based on the need, you can further flatten if needed:

```
LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[ [LoadBalancerName, DNSName, Scheme, SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName, SecurityGroups, Instances[*].InstanceId][] ][]
```

gives

```yaml
- - my-load-balancer
  - my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
  - internet-facing
  - my-elb-sg
  - sg-a61988c3
  - i-207d9717
  - i-afefb49b
```

And

```
LoadBalancerDescriptions[*].[ [LoadBalancerName, DNSName, Scheme, SourceSecurityGroup.GroupName, SecurityGroups, Instances[*].InstanceId][] ][][]
```

gives

```yaml
- my-load-balancer
- my-load-balancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
- internet-facing
- my-elb-sg
- sg-a61988c3
- i-207d9717
- i-afefb49b
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the effort you put into answering this question